# difference between the background-size

Tags: css

While working I found something interesting difference when using `background-size`:

```
html,body{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.wrap{
    position: relative;
    z-index: auto;
    width: 960px;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#main{
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%;
}
main{
    max-width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: url(images/img-main.png) no-repeat center;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

So, now when I use background-size: 100% 100%; it works perfectly but background-size: 100%; doesn't work as 100% 100%.

---

**background-size: 100% 100%**

[image]

**background-size: 100%**

[image]

---

But I was thinking `background-size: 100%;` works as `background-size: 100% 100%;`. So, is there difference between them really? And why this works differently?

Comment: [just curious] You seems to be a pro in css (_from your points and badges_). can't you just go through docs like MDN or W3C? Sorry, but this question looks silly to me..

Comment: I wasn't noticed the difference before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**background-size: 100%** means the 100% defines the width of the image, the height is implicitly set to 'auto'

**background-size: 100% 100%** sets both height and width to 100%.

That is the difference between **background-size: 100%** and **background-size: 100% 100%**

The background-size property is supported in IE9+, Firefox, Opera, Chrome, and Safari.

Answer (score 2):

When you use `background-size: 100% 100%;` means `x` and `y` are set to `100%` respectively, when you are using `background-size: 100%;` sets `width` to `100%` and `height` is `auto`

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size) :

> One-value syntax: the value defines the width of the image, the height
>   is implicitly set to 'auto'

---

Though, MDN suggests to ignore using `auto` for `background-size` property...

[image]

Reason:

> Note that it's particularly not recommended to use a pixel dimension
>   and an auto dimension with a gradient, because it's impossible to
>   replicate rendering in versions of Firefox prior to 8, and in browsers
>   not implementing Firefox 8's rendering, without knowing the exact size
>   of the element whose background is being specified.

<sup>Credits : Mozilla Developer Network</sup>

Answer (score 0):

"*percentage* Sets the width and height of the background image in percent of the parent element. The first value sets the width, the second value sets the height. If only one value is given, the second is set to "auto" "

[reference](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp)

Yes. Interesting :)